# Не понимаю как работает result type возвращаемый parse()

Tags: rust, match

Это рабочий код, начал изучать раст, читаю официальную книгу по порядку, решил создать прогу, в которую вводим два числа, и сравниваем их

```
use std::io;

fn main() {

    let mut num1 = 0;
    let mut num2 = 0;

    let mut num1_state = false;

    loop {
        let mut num_to_enter : u8;

        if num1_state == false {
            num_to_enter = 1;
        } else {
            num_to_enter = 2;
        }
        println!("Enter {num_to_enter} num:");

        let mut temp_num= String::new();
        match io::stdin()
            .read_line(&mut temp_num) {
                Ok(n) => n,
                Err(_) => {
                    println!("failed to read a line");
                    continue;
                }
            };

        let temp_num: i32 = match temp_num.trim().parse() {
            Ok(n) => n,
            Err(_) => {
                println!("Enter a num");
                continue;
            },
        };

        if num1_state == false {
            num1 = temp_num;
            num1_state = true;
        } else {
            num2 = temp_num;
            break;
        }
    }

    println!("You entered num1 = {num1} and num2 = {num2}");

    if num1 > num2 {
        println!("{num1} > {num2}");
    } else {
        println!("{num2} > {num1}");
    }
}
```

Но почему-то тот же код, вне цикла не работает(если убрать continue соотвественно)

```
let temp_num: i32 = match temp_num.trim().parse() {
        Ok(n) => n,
        Err(_) => {
            println!("Enter a num");
        },
    };
```

Выдает ошибку `Type mismatch [E0308] expected` i32`, but found` ()`

Comment: Вы убрали continue - а значит ветка Err больше не прерывает работу и возвращает какое-то значение. А так как в конце ветки Err стоит точка с запятой - значит возвращается пустой кортеж, хотя очевидно должен быть i32, отчего и ошибка

Comment: @andreymal спасибо

Comment: @andreymal а если мне надо поменять булевую перменную в случае Err, но при это продолжить выполнение кода после 

let temp_num: i32 = match temp_num.trim().parse() {
        Ok(n) => n,
        Err(_) => {
            println!("Enter a num");
            flag = false;

        },
    };

Comment: А какое значение должна иметь переменная `temp_num: i32` при продолжении кода?

Comment: @andreymal она должна быть int чтобы стравнить ее можно было
А вот в таком случае, когда при ошибке надо поменять значение перменной, что можно сделать?
 `let mut flag = true;`
 `let temp_num: i32 = match temp_num.trim().parse() {`
 `Ok(n) => n,`
 `Err(_) => {`
  `println!("Enter a num");`
  `flag = false;`
   `},`
    `};`

Comment: Вопрос всё тот же — какое значение должна иметь переменная `temp_num: i32` при ошибке и последующем продолжении кода?

Comment: @andreymal значения int32 или передать инфу, что произошла ошибка и переменная в int32 не переведена

Comment: Тип `i32` не может иметь значение «произошла ошибка». Если же вы очень хотите, чтобы переменная `temp_num` могла хранить в себе значение «произошла ошибка», значит вы должны изменить её тип на `Result<i32>` или типа того

Comment: Ну и события «переменная в int32 не переведена» наступить тоже никогда не может. Если уж вы написали `let temp_num: i32 =` значит вы обязаны передать туда какое-то конкретное значение i32 или преждевременно завершить работу (как делал continue в цикле)

Comment: @andreymal, `()` - это не *"пустой кортеж"*, а так называемый *unit type* - пустой тип.

Comment: @wchistow ах да, привычка из питона)

Comment: @wchistow но всё-таки [The Rust Reference говорит](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/types/tuple.html), что unit type это "tuple type with no fields"